# CSS vertical align text in a section tag?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I posted an example of what I'm doing

```css
.open-text {
  color: pink;
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  /* display: flex !important; */
  /* align-items: center !important; */
  background: #1e3a87;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1 class="open-text">
    <br/>
    Lorem Ipsum: usage. Lorem ipsum is a pseudo-Latin text used in web design, typography, layout, and printing in place of English to emphasise design elements over content. It's also called placeholder (or filler) text.your life.
  </h1>
</section>
```

How do I put the text in the center and make it a centered column with a width that doesn't take up the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

Your attempts with `display: flex` works, just remove the `<br/>` (and I also added an `height` so you we can see that this centred):

```css
  .open-text {
        color: pink;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background: #1e3a87;
        font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
        height:200px;
    }
```

```html
  <section>
     <h1 class="open-text">
    Lorem Ipsum: usage. Lorem ipsum is a pseudo-Latin text used in web design, typography, layout, and printing in place of English to emphasise design elements over content. It's also called placeholder (or filler) text.your life.
     </h1>
    </section>
```